# Animating math and physics with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, react

I love math, physics, animations and JS. For my project, I want to create modern (interactive) animations with JS that I can include on our React.js (Gatsby) website. Which tools are great for accomplishing this?

What I want to make:

1. Small animations, e.g. the unfolding of a cube, that can be repeated over and over
2. Interactive animations (draggable objects, only display when certain action occurs...)
3. Animations where parameters (like speed, weight...) can be adjusted to run physics simulations (like applets)

This should be integrated into a static Gatsby website (through md file parser). I think JS is the best language to do this. But how do I start, which libraries can I use?

Thanks in advance!